# Book recommendations for Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation

I'm doing a PhD thesis about Riemannian geometry and i would like to improve my knowledge. I know all the basic defintions and concepts (I have the "semiRiemannian geometry with applications to relativity" from Barret O'neill and i have studied it during the degree and the master ). So i'm looking for books with the following to characteritics: First, a book which go forward with respect the content of O'neill's book. Secondly, it would be great that the author/s stop in the basic (or advanced) concepts to think about it and not just give the defintions and going on.

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

My former advisor at ucla Peter Petersen wrote the GTM *Riemannian Geometry* book.  I had a copy of it when it was in manuscript form, some 30 years ago.

I never mastered the subject.  It seems to be exceedingly difficult to do.  Nevertheless, all the "yellow peril" books are known for being very high quality.

I always said that my advisor, Peter, seemed to be quite sound.  Even though he couldn't help me write my thesis and get my phd.

---

There is also the book by the "french guys", Galot, Hulin and Lafontaine.